# Is there a wordpress function restrict public email id for registration like as is_email()

Tags: email

I am trying to implement user registration only from the work email not with public emails like Gmail, yahoo, outlook, etc
user registration will be through only with a business email I am able to implement a valid email but not work email restriction.

```
    if (!is_email($signup_email)) {
        echo json_encode(array('signedup' => false, 'message' => __('Invalid Email!', 'piperegistration')));
        exit();
    }
    if (email_exists($signup_email)) {
        echo json_encode(array('signedup' => false, 'message' => __('Email already exists!', 'piperegistration')));
        exit();
    }
    if (6 > strlen($signup_pass)) {
        echo json_encode(array('signedup' => false, 'message' => __('Password too short. Please enter at least 6 characters!', 'piperegistration')));
        exit();
    }
```

I am still in the learning phase so please help me out

Comment: There's nothing like that built in, no. If you have a list of free email domain names you want to exclude you could write code for that, or you might be able to use an email verification API that will tell you if an email address is from a free service or not, and there may already be plugins for those, but I haven't see one / can't recommend one.

Comment: You don't normally ask the user for a password either, BTW - the site will generate a random password and email it to them. Or if you really want to there's the zxcvbnm library built in you can use for password strength checks.

Comment: @rup if I create a new function that will check from the array where I will put public domain like Gmail, yahoo, outlook, and AOL if it matches then `echo json_encode(array('signedup' => false, 'message' => __('Email already exists!', 'piperegistration')));
        exit();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to ensure that the email address contains the "work email" domain, you might be able to use the [`is_email`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/is_email/) filter (using the `null` context will make sure this is the last check in the [`is_email()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_email/) function).

Let's assume your work emails are all of the form `user@example.com`.

```
add_filter( 'is_email', 'wpse_413882_check_domain', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Checks to make sure we're using a work email address.
 *
 * @param  string|boolean $is_email The email address, or false.
 * @param  string         $email    The email address to check.
 * @param  string|null    $context  What context we're checking. We want `null`.
 * @return string|boolean           The email address, or false on failure.
 */
function wpse_413882_check_domain( $is_email, $email, $context ) {
    if null !== $context {
        return $is_email;
    }
    if ( false === strpos( '@example.com', $email ) ) {
        // We're not using a work email address. Fail the test.
        return false;
    }
    return $is_email;
}
```